# PHPExcel Repeat Columns at Left

Tags: phpexcel

I just want to repeat columns at left from my excel report.
I used PHPExcel, and the function

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->getColumnsToRepeatAtLeft();

The problem is I don't know how and where should I put the parameters.
I only want to repeat Column A and B every page.
Thanks for the help :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setColumnsToRepeatAtLeftByStartAndEnd('A', 'B');
```

This should work.